# Why is a void method getting a NullPointerException on a mocked object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am writing unit tests for my java app that analyzes commits to Stash, an atlassian app similar to Github.

The method that I am testing is this one:

```
public List<Message> processEvent(RepositoryRefsChangedEvent event) {
    ArrayList<Message> commitList = new ArrayList<Message>();

    for (RefChange refChange : event.getRefChanges()) {
        LOGGER.info("checking ref change refId={} fromHash={} toHash={} type={}", refChange.getRefId(), refChange.getFromHash(),
                refChange.getToHash(), refChange.getType());

        if (refChange.getRefId().startsWith(REF_BRANCH)) {
            if (refChange.getType() == RefChangeType.ADD && isDeleted(refChange)) {
                LOGGER.info("Deleted a ref that never existed. This shouldn't ever occur.");
            }
            else if (isDeleted(refChange) || isCreated(refChange)) {
                branchCreation(refChange, event.getRepository(), commitList);
            }
            else {
                sepCommits.findCommitInfo(refChange, event.getRepository(), commitList);
            }
        }
        else {
            refNotProcessed(refChange);
        }
    }
    return commitList;
}
```

I am trying to make sure that if I have a git notes commit, the processing is ignored and `refNotProcessed(..)` is called.

Luckily, I was able to figure this out with relative ease and came to the below solution:

```
@RunWith (MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RefChangEventTest {
    @Mock RefChange ref;
    @Mock RepositoryRefsChangedEvent refsChangedEvent;
    @Mock Repository repo;
    @Mock ApplicationPropertiesService appService;
    @Mock SEPCommits sepCommits;
    @Spy SEPRefChangeEventImpl sepRefChangeEvent = new SEPRefChangeEventImpl(sepCommits, appService);

    @Before
    public void testSetup() {
        Collection<RefChange> refList = new ArrayList<RefChange>(1);
        refList.add(ref);
        when(refsChangedEvent.getRefChanges()).thenReturn(refList);
        when(refsChangedEvent.getRepository()).thenReturn(repo);
    }

    @Test
    public void gitNotesAreIgnored() throws Exception {
        when(ref.getRefId()).thenReturn("refs/notes/foo");
        when(ref.getFromHash()).thenReturn("da69d7e202d7f66cba01c6f4030bd5975adbf200");
        when(ref.getToHash()).thenReturn("da69d7e202d7f66cba01c6f4030bd5975adbf201");
        doNothing().when(sepCommits).findCommitInfo(any(RefChange.class), any(Repository.class), any(ArrayList.class));

        sepRefChangeEvent.processEvent(refsChangedEvent);
        verify(sepRefChangeEvent, times(1)).refNotProcessed(ref);
    }
```

After this, I wanted to see if my unit tests would fail for the right reasons if I changed the ref name to something expected like `refs/heads/foo`. I'd want to see something along the lines of: `expected 1 execution of refNotProcessed but was not run at all`

Instead I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.cray.stash.SEPRefChangeEventImpl.processEvent(SEPRefChangeEventImpl.java:62)
at ut.com.isroot.stash.plugin.RefChangEventTest.gitNotesAreIgnored(RefChangEventTest.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:253)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Which points to the call to `sepCommits.findCommitInfo(..)` By default, methods with void signatures do nothing when a mock calls them. That's exactly what I want it to do. I want it to be called but do nothing but record the fact that `sepCommits` was interacted with. Why is an NPE happening?

Here are some more methods people are asking for:

```
public SEPRefChangeEventImpl(SEPCommits sepCommits, ApplicationPropertiesService appService) {
    this.sepCommits = sepCommits;

    try {
        endpoint = appService.getPluginProperty("plugin.fedmsg.events.relay.endpoint");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to retrieve properties\n" + e);
    }

    if (endpoint == null) {
        endpoint = "tcp://some.web.address"
    }
}


public void refNotProcessed(RefChange refChange) {
    LOGGER.info("This type of refChange is not supported.\n refId={} fromHash={} toHash={} type={}", refChange.getRefId(), refChange.getFromHash(),
            refChange.getToHash(), refChange.getType());
}

public void findCommitInfo(RefChange ref, Repository repo, ArrayList<Message> commitList) {
    Page<Commit> commits = getChangeset(repo, ref);
    for (Commit commit : commits.getValues()) {
        String topic = topicPrefix + repo.getProject().getKey() + "." + repo.getName() + ".commit";
        Message message = new Message(getInfo(commit, ref), topic);
        commitList.add(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problems in the code (but spy() I don't like). Can you show all methods/fields/constructors used ?

Comment: The spy is necessary to run verify on sepRefChangeEvent cause it needs a mock to run on. I added more methods for reference!

Comment: Ok I watched, no special thing. You could try without spying ?

Comment: Just to check that mocking work without spying. Anyway, as your problem is not solved, I will propose another way of doing in an answer

Comment: You're essentially saying to replace the @Spy with @Mock, right? I tried that and the method no longer runs (I discovered this using the debugger) because I'm assuming the @Mock reference make the object null and it has no method to run. Note, the object needs to be a Mock object so I can run the `verify` method on it.

Comment: I answered to all your comments in comments in my answer to avoid crossed conversations

Comment: What is happening on SEPRefChangeEventImpl line 62? Have you tried adding a breakpoint to it and debugging? Adding a @Spy to the object means it's being executed, using the SEPCommits mock. Any call on that would return null, as it has no further mocking specified.

Comment: @KoosGadellaa Yeah, I've debugged it and it's doing exactly as you say. According to mockino docs though, executing a void method on a mocked object doesn't do anything, and that's exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: Main question is: why are you testing the sepCommits.findCommitInfo method in your test of processEvent? That should be done in its own class, right?

Comment: Yeah, the actual processing done by `findCommitInfo(..)` is tested in another unit test class. I was simply using the fact that that method was executed as a sign that the processing filtered/didn't filter out what commit types to process. Another idea I was avoiding was having a middle-man method execute `findCommitInfo(..)` and then running `verify(..)` on that middle man method.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in your setup, `sepCommits` is a dependency in the class, containing the `processEvent()` method.

You have to inject the mock you are creating in your test in the `sepRefChangeEvent` variable. Normally this is done either by passing it as a parameter during construction or via a setter method. I see no such code in your test class. I think you are actually hitting a real instance, and not the mocked one there and this is causing the exception.

Comment: When I instantiate my `sepRefChangeEvent` variable I pass it `sepCommits` in the first param.

Comment: Oh, sorry, must've missed that one. But why are you spying on your tested instance? What happens if you just use a normal instance of the tested class?

Comment: No worries! If I declare it as a normal instance, I get an error when using it in `verify(sepRefChangeEvent, times(1)).refNotProcessed(ref)` because verify needs a mock to work on.

Comment: Can you try and comment out the verification and just run the code to see if you'll invoke the original method again?

Comment: I've actually tried this already! When I comment out the verify code, I get the same error. Is this significant? I expected this because the method that leads to the error occurs because I run `sepRefChangeEvent.processEvent(refsChangedEvent)`.

Comment: I think you should debug your `processEvent` method while executing the test and check if indeed you have managed to inject the mocks. If you are indeed doing that, maybe try and replace `doNothing()` with an empty implementation of `doAnswer(new Answer<Void>()...)` just to check if this may cause some sort of issue in your case. Also, adding the complete stack trace might be helpful.

Comment: I debugged that method, it hit a break point and the sepCommits object was null, so I'm assuming that means it was successfully mocked. I also used doAnswer and overrode answer() to just simply return a null and got the same error.

Comment: If you got `null`, this means that you never initialised the dependency and it is NOT mocked.

Comment: Oh ok, that's good to know. It isn't initialized, you see my code. I've only declared it. If I construct a full SEPCommits object, then the method `findCommitInfo(...)` does this massive amount of processing that requires me to stub everything. Ideally, I just want it to hit `findCommitInfo(...)`, not do anything, and report that it hit that method.

Comment: So, what do you get as a value for the `sepCommits` field inside your tested `SEPRefChangeEventImpl` instance? Was it `null`?

Comment: Yep, that's what I get.

Comment: OK, a new theory - try moving you initialisation logic to the `testSetup()` method. Maybe inline initialisation happens way too early, before the test runner has the change to inject mocks into your fields and you end up passing `null` to the constructor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121073/discussion-between-scott-james-walter-and-danail-alexiev).

Comment: Yeah, I tried that with similar results. I found a solution, although I'm not sure if it's a good one. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that Mockito spying is not a natural behavior since your class is both mock and class to test.  
In legacy code, it may be acceptable but in new code, it's a pity.

Besides, in your case, I think you don't need spying. 
Your logic is : if `ref name` input matchs with `REF_BRANCH`, you do processing else you do nothing. So, you should need to check that in the accepted test, you do the processing (your verify mock is called) and that in the no accepted test, you don't perform the processing (you verify mock is not called).

```
       // You do the processing
       if (refChange.getRefId().startsWith(REF_BRANCH)) {
            if (refChange.getType() == RefChangeType.ADD && isDeleted(refChange)) {
                LOGGER.info("Deleted a ref that never existed. This shouldn't ever occur.");
            }
            else if (isDeleted(refChange) || isCreated(refChange)) {
                branchCreation(refChange, event.getRepository(), commitList);
            }
            else {
                sepCommits.findCommitInfo(refChange, event.getRepository(), commitList);
            }
        }
        // You do nothing
        else {
            refNotProcessed(refChange);
        }
```

Asserting that another public method of the tested class is called as acceptance test is not an acceptance test.

If you want really to test it, another solution is introducing a new class to move the `public method refNotProcessed` inside it. 
You could keep this class to control flow in input and dispatch to a processing method in the processing class :

```
       // You do the processing
       if (refChange.getRefId().startsWith(REF_BRANCH)) {
            if (refChange.getType() == RefChangeType.ADD && isDeleted(refChange)) {
                LOGGER.info("Deleted a ref that never existed. This shouldn't ever occur.");
            }
            else if (isDeleted(refChange) || isCreated(refChange)) {
                processClass.branchCreation(refChange, event.getRepository(), commitList);
            }
            else {
                sepCommits.findCommitInfo(refChange, event.getRepository(), commitList);
            }
        }
        // You do nothing
        else {
            processClass.refNotProcessed(refChange);
        }
```

Comment: This seems like good advice, but it probably won't solve my problem. You're essentially telling me to put `refNotProcessed` and `branchCreation` into a different class. I'm still going to have the same issue.

Comment: I will all answer here to not have crossed messages.
No, I propose you to remove the  spy annotation, but not to replace it with Mock. Use it as a natural object. I think that if you stop using spying, you would have no more the problem to mock `processClass`

Comment: My test uses `verify` as its validation. The `verify` method NEEDS a mock object to work with. I cannot use a non-mock sepRefChangeEvent variable. I will get a "NotAMockException". If I want to run verify on that variable it NEEDS to be a mock.

Comment: Yes but  don't use spy and comment the line where your `verify` the spy just to check if without spying, mocking sepCommits works or not. Just a test to try to isolate the problem. It is not the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
@RunWith (MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RefChangEventTest {
    @Mock RefChange ref;
    @Mock RepositoryRefsChangedEvent refsChangedEvent;
    @Mock ApplicationPropertiesService appService;
    @Mock ArrayList<Message> mockList;
    @Mock RepositoryService repositoryService;
    @Mock RefService refService;
    @Mock CommitService commitService;
    @Mock SecurityService securityService;
    @Mock Repository repo;

    SEPCommits sepCommits = mock(SEPCommits.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    @Spy SEPRefChangeEventImpl sepRefChangeEvent = new SEPRefChangeEventImpl(sepCommits, appService);

    @Before
    public void testSetup() {
        Collection<RefChange> refList = new ArrayList<RefChange>(1);
        refList.add(ref);
        when(refsChangedEvent.getRefChanges()).thenReturn(refList);
        when(refsChangedEvent.getRepository()).thenReturn(repo);
    }

    @Test
    public void gitNotesAreIgnored() throws Exception {
        when(ref.getRefId()).thenReturn("refs/notes/foo");
        when(ref.getFromHash()).thenReturn("da69d7e202d7f66cba01c6f4030bd5975adbf200");
        when(ref.getToHash()).thenReturn("da69d7e202d7f66cba01c6f4030bd5975adbf201");

        sepRefChangeEvent.processEvent(refsChangedEvent);
        verifyZeroInteractions(sepCommits);
    }
```

The difference is how the sepCommits is mocked, it's with `RETURN_DEEP_STUBS`. The reason I'm avoiding fully initializing sepCommits is because then I need to stun a ton of methods that go on inside `findCommitInfo(..)`. I just want to ensure that that method is either called or not. I'm not sure if `RETURN_DEEP_STUBS` is a good solution but it worked for me.